# Need Help understanding the philosophy behind splitting the integrals into sqrt(x)

Tags: integration, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Quite occasionally we see in number theory the below integral evaluated as such:

$$\int_{2}^{x} \frac{dt}{\log t}= \int_{2}^{\sqrt x}\frac{dt}{\log t} + \int_{\sqrt x}^{x}\frac{dt}{\log t} $$

Why the choice of $\sqrt x$ And how does it help facilitate the integral and estimating it.

Comment: I do not think you would get an explanation for this without citing a source for this equation. There is no one reason  to do so. For example in some elementary number theory problems it is helpful to write as $(a+b)^2$ as $(a-b)^2+4ab.$ We cannot say much about this decomposition without looking at the particular problem. I found noting about this on the to-go source [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function)

Comment: Think of $\sqrt{x}$ as a *multiplicative* midway point between $1$ and $x$, which for a function like $\log t$ is much more effective because the value $\log \sqrt{x} = (1/2)\log x$ is below the endpoint value $\log x$ by a definite proportion while at the additive midway point (essentially) $x/2$ there is no useful decay at all, as $\log(x/2) = \log x - \log 2$ is basically as large as $\log x$ itself (when $x$ is big).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part fits inside a box of width $\sqrt x$ and height $1/\ln2$ so its integral is less than $\sqrt x/\ln 2$.
The second part fits inside a box of width $x$ and height $1/\ln\sqrt x$ so its integral is less than $2x/\ln x$.
The first part is narrow and tall, the second part is wide but short.  Their combined area is much less than the simplest estimate of $x/\ln 2$ that comes from a single box of width $x$ and height $1/\ln2$.

$\sqrt x$ was chosen to be a fairly simple compromise, where $\sqrt x=o(x)$  and $1/\ln\sqrt x=O(1/\ln x)=o(1/\ln2)$

$$\int_2^{\sqrt x}\frac{dt}{\ln t}\lt\int_2^{\sqrt x}\frac{dt}{\ln2}\\=\frac{\sqrt x -2}{\ln2}$$
$$\int_{\sqrt x}^x\frac{dt}{\ln t}\lt\int_{\sqrt x}^x\frac{dt}{\ln\sqrt x}\\ \lt\frac x{\ln\sqrt x}$$

Comment: I might be able to grasp the second half of your answer, but I’m still struggling with the first part and the square dimensions.

Comment: @WalidMohammed. $f(t)=1/\ln t$ is monotonic, strictly decreasing for $t\ge 2$.  So if $2\le A<B$ then $(B-A)f(B)=\int_A^Bf(B)dt<\int_A^B f(t)dt<\int_A^Bf(A)dt=(B-A)f(A).$